# How can Retrieve Playlist in youtube v3 in android?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to get my playlist of youtube? In v3 is it possible ? if have any idea than please share with me. Thanks...

Comment: This will work, but it'll be helpful to see the code you have tried before we answer. The easiest way is probably to use Play Services and the V3 API.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, use this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists
```

and parse the response

```
{
"kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
"etag": etag,
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": integer,
"resultsPerPage": integer
},
 "nextPageToken": string,
 "prevPageToken": string,
 "items": [
 playlists Resource
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The parameter `mine=true` is very important since you only want your playlist. Remember to have a correct authorization before this otherwise you will have HTTP status code 401 (Unauthorized).

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) for more details about this service. You can simulate it there too.

Comment: i tried this but i could not get right response. my url is this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&key=AIzaSyCl-KeJdkqQ2l3nWDydAtbfhnYVfTo9NCQ    Can you help me?

Comment: @HirenPatel, I've never worked with this API before, but as I said before you must do authentication before playlist calling. Take a look on the following link for the authentication matter, it might help. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication